# Avoid linebreak after INCLUDETEXT fields

Tags: ms-word, field, line-breaks

I am trying to include data from a text file (one text file that only contains a  single number)

I am able to include this number in the INCLUDETEXT fiel (so the link work) , but at the creation there is a line break just **after** the field (not in the field). I can remove it, but as soon as I update the field values, the line break commes back.

Has anyone observed this strange behavior?

Comment: What you are describing is the expected behaviour; there is nothing strange about it. In any event, this is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., SuperUser, MS Answers).

Comment: The only way this has a chance of working is to nest the { INCLUDETEXT } field inside an { = } field.